# Memory synchronization with atomic operations in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers

I am currently implementing a parallel program in C which includes a message-passing/work-sharing/work-stealing component.  Basically, threads are going to share data by sending pointers to data to each other.  For a number of reasons, I believe that atomic operations are most appropriate for my use case rather than mutexes (i.e., to share work, one thread can simply atomically store a pointer to that work in the inbox of another thread).  However, I am a bit concerned about "freshness" of data when it comes to sharing pointers.  My understanding is that when using C11 atomics, it is not guaranteed that atomically updating a variable will also synchronize memory (such that the mutations performed by one thread do not become immediately become visible to the thread that received the pointer from another thread), as one thread could have stale data cached at that pointer.  My questions are:

- Is my understanding of using C11 atomics to share pointers correct?
- If so, is there a standard approach for memory synchronization that I can leverage?
- If there isn't, is there a better solution in the GCC atomic extensions?  Or should I avoid all of this and just use mutexes, even if they are a heavyweight solution for my purposes?

Comment: As long as you use `memory_order_seq_cst`, you shouldn't have problems with memory synchronization. You still have to be careful, but you're not getting races.

Comment: Just use mutexes. This kind of premature optimization will make a project twice as hard to write, twice as hard to maintain, and half as likely to work.

Comment: Well, it would be nice to have an actual answer to my questions, even if (for now) mutexes turn out to be the easiest and most practical solution.

Comment: Please provide more details - what way you are going to share pointers

Comment: @EOF: You are right, but that will also slow down the program massively. One should use atomics wisely and well thought. There are many resources online about this (far by most complicated) new C11 feature.

Comment: There are many online-resources which explain this feature in detail. You can also use the C++ stdatomics, because they have been intentionally implemented (almost?) identical.

Comment: @Olaf: Well, whether it slows the program down "massively" depends on the program and the implementation. On x86, for example, `memory_order_seq_cst` isn't too far from the default.

Comment: @EOF: Well, just because that is a strongly ordered architecture and x86 does a massive effort to snoop, etc. All for the tons of broken code in the wild which would crash instantly otherwise. This is different on unordered archs like ARM and other RISCs.